# StackOverFlow Recursividad con suma

Tags: java

tengo un trabajo en el cual consiste en regresar la suma de un recorrido en donde tengo 3 opciones y cada opcion equivale a X tiempo, aquí a continuación: 

opc | Tiempo

1 = 3m
2 = 5m
3 = 7m

Y tengo que mostrar la suma del tiempo.
El problema al momento de intentar hacer la recursividad llamando al metodo al momento de ejecutarlo me salir el StackOverFlow les anexo el codigo, esperando una ayudadita por que estoy muy atascado con esto :(

Codigo:

```
public class Raton {
    static int sum = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Variables globales
        int numero=0;
        int resultado=0;
        // Fin de VG
        System.out.println("El recorrido fue:");
        while(numero != 3){
            numero = (int) (Math.random()*3)+1; //Se genera un numero random del 1 al 3
            System.out.print(numero+ " "); //Muestro el numero generado en cada ciclo
            resultado = moverse(numero); //Le paso por argumento el numero generado al metodo moverse()

        }
        System.out.println("\n\nEl tiempo total del recorrido fue: \n" + resultado);    
    }

    //Metodos

    public static int moverse(int n){ //Paso por parametro el numero generado
        if (n == 1) {
            return 3 + moverse(n);
        }else if (n == 2){
            return 5 + moverse(n);
        }else{
            return 7 + moverse(n);
        }
    }
} // fin de la clase
```

Salida:

```
El recorrido fue:
3 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at Raton.moverse(Raton.java:33)
        at Raton.moverse(Raton.java:33)
        at Raton.moverse(Raton.java:33)
        at Raton.moverse(Raton.java:33)
Un monton de veces mas....
```

Comment: Por favor no agregues la respuesta a tu pregunta, con marcar la respuesta que te ayudo como aceptada alcanza ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que esta ocurriendo es que estás haciendo que n nunca cambie, es decir siempre va a valer lo mismo, por lo tanto nunca vas a salir del método recursivo. Por lo tanto la generación del número aleatorio deberías realizarla dentro del método como valor de n, además tu método debería tener un final y por lo que he entendido el final es que salga el número 3.

Pd: Deberías quitar el while que tienes en el main, porque sino vas a ejecutar el método muchisímas veces. Te recomiendo solo realizar una ejecución de un numero aleatorio y después pasárselo al método y que el mismo siga con la generación de los siguientes.

Pd2: Si quieres mostrar cada número que se ha generado simplemente muestra n en un System.out... cada vez antes de realizar cada return.

```
public static int moverse(int n) {
        if(n==1) {
            return 3 + moverse((int) (Math.random()*3)+1);
        }else if(n==2) {
            return 5 + moverse((int) (Math.random()*3)+1);
        }else {
            return 7;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, esto dio solución a todo, no lo había pensado de esta manera <3

Comment: Aun que si te soy sincero me revuelve un poco el como trabaja, creo fue mi error desde el inicio por no saber como funciona, te molesto si me explicas? :( modificare el como me quedo

Comment: No hay ningún problema, no molestas en absoluto!

Answer (score 2):

De tu código, y tu ejercicio, no entiendo nada.. pero puedo explicarte tu problema de recursividad.

En una funcion recursiva, siempre, pero siempre, tiene que haber una opcion que termine la recursividad.

En tu función, no existe esa opcion. Siempre estas volviendo a entrar. Entonces no hay forma de que termine la misma.

Es mas, n siempre vale lo mismo, porque nunca le cambias el valor, asi que es una funcion infinita.

Tu funcion, para que sea recursiva, deberia ser, **como ejemplo**

```
public static int moverse(int n){
    if (n == 1) {
        return 3; //Sin volver a llamarse a si misma!
    }else if (n == 2){
        return 5 + moverse(n); //n deberia ser otra cosa.. un random tal vez?
    }else{
        return 7 + moverse(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: eh intentado hacer lo que dices pero sigue dando el error, intente hacerlo de otra manera que parece funcionar pero me suma el resultado anterior con el siguiente y la verdad no se si en este caso se este aplicando la recursividad ya que no estoy llamando al metodo :s
`public static int moverse(int n){
        if (n == 3) {
            return sum = 7 + sum;
        }else if (n == 2){
            return sum = 5 + sum;
        }else{
            return sum = 3+ sum;
        } `
Y igualmente intente comentar el código de arriba para que se pueda entender un poco mejor.

Comment: Genera la lista de valores con la cantidad que quieras antes de entrar en la funcion recursiva, y luego ejecuta la funcion recursiva. Esa funcion que escribiste en el comentario sufre los problemas exactamente igual que la de arriba. Donde se cambia el valor que estas revisando? @iTzprodigui